Select column values while setting minimum to 0
I'm trying to select from a table that is many rows, but only two columns, they are timestamp and value.  I need to select all timestamps, regardless of the value, but want only the non-negative values.  Meaning, if the table looked like this:



timestamp
value




2021-01-01 00:00:00
1


2021-01-01 00:01:00
-2


2021-01-01 00:02:00
3



...my selection would show:



timestamp
value




2021-01-01 00:00:00
1


2021-01-01 00:01:00
0


2021-01-01 00:02:00
3



If I included WHERE value >= 0 in my query, then I'd miss the 00:01:00 timestamp.
I'm hoping it's something simple like: SELECT timestamp, MAX(value, 0) FROM my_table but of course, that's not how MAX() works.  Is there another function I'm missing?

CASE WHEN value < 0 THEN 0 ELSE value END?  Or IF(value<0, 0, value);?

Those sound like great options, thank you!  You know if either is more performant?  It could be hundreds of thousands or millions of rows.

How about GREATEST(value, 0)? GREATEST() works the way you were hoping MAX() would work.

@Barmar - Yes!  That is the answer.  The simplest route to what I was looking for.  Thank you!

A WHERE-Clause will filter records, so when you say "I need to select all timestamps, regardless of the value"  you should NOT add a WHERE-clause to your SQL statement.
